# CSV header based on JSON dictionary keys

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a JSON like this for example:

```
[
    {
        'name':'test1',
        'random1':'random_1_value'
    },
    {
        'name':'test2',
        'random2':'random_2_value'
        'random4':'random_4_value'
    },
    {
        'name':'test3',
        'random3':'random_3_value'
    },
]
```

I want to convert this JSON and construct CSV header based on dictionary keys. Then fill each row respectively. Expected output:

```
name, random1, random2, random4, random3
test1, random_1_value
test2, ,random_2_value, random_4_value, ,
test3, , , , random_3_value
```

This is my code so far:

```
data = json.loads(open('output_data.json').read())
csvwriter = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))
count = 0
for emp in data:
    if count == 0:
        header = emp.keys()
        csvwriter.writerow(header)
        count += 1
    csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())
```

Comment: Is `pandas` an option?

Comment: @Chris I'd like to stay away from pandas as of now.

Comment: Are you interested in a very very short and easy command line solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) and [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) modules in the standard library to do this.

We can use a [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to get the column names in the order in which they appear.

We use an `OrderedDict` so that the code will work with versions of Python earlier than 3.7.  From Python 3.7 onwards the language **guarantees** that ordinary dictionaries remember the order in which their keys were inserted. If your code will only be run by Python 3.7+ you can use the [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) builtin instead of an `OrderedDict`.

```
headers = collections.OrderedDict((key, None) for dict_ in data for key in dict_)
```

Now that the column names have been generated, use a [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write each dictionary in the data to the output file.  `DictWriter` automatically handles missing keys, ensuring that each data item is written to the right column.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newlines='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
    # Write the column names to file.
    writer.writeheader()
    # Write the data to file.
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `with` operator when reading and writing files. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445919/5491375)

```
# Open the JSON file
>>> with open('csv.json') as f:
...     data = json.load(f)

# Get the column names
>>> col = [k for d in data for k in d]

# Create a matrix of the data
>>> matrix = [[d['name']] + [d.get(c, '') for c in col] for d in data]

>>> csv_data = [['name'] + col] + matrix

>>> with open('json.csv', 'w') as f:
...     writer = csv.writer(f)
...     writer.writerows(csv_data)
```